# Finding cities within radius usingPostGIS?

Tags: postgis

I'm new to PostGIS and I'm just trying to get a good grasp of the basics.

I've taken a dataset containing information on the world's cities, from https://www.maxmind.com/en/free-world-cities-database and imported it into a table.

I added a geometry column with:

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('cities', 'geom', 4326, 'POINT', 2);
```

And then populated the column with:

```
UPDATE cities SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude), 4326);
```

I want to find all cities within the radius of a specific lat/lon. To do that I tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM cities
WHERE ST_DWithin(geom, ST_MakePoint(79.3832,43.6532)::geography, 50000);
```

...but no results are returned. The lat/lon I entered is that of the city of Toronto and I've verified that a record for Toronto exists in the table with the correct lat/lon.

If I increase the radius to something ridiculous, such as "5000000" a list of cities - most of which appear to be places on other continents - is returned.
What am I doing wrong? Is it my query? Am I filling the geom column incorrectly?

Comment: You're comparing geometry with geography. Did you try `WHERE ST_DWithin(geom::geography, ST_MakePoint(79.3832,43.6532)::geography, 50000);` ?

Comment: @RoVo Thank you for the suggestion. I tried it now but still, no results. :(

Comment: your point is somewhere in Kasachstan, with Almaty the next bigger city being 200 km away... but you search a radius of 50km. Sure that you're doing the right thing?

Comment: I guess you want to search for -79...

Comment: @RoVo If I enter those coordinates into Google Maps it drops a pin in the center of Toronto. I also got the coordinates by looking them up.

Comment: You lost the "W" on the way, which means West or negative longitude (-). If I enter the coordinates into GMaps, it's in Kasachsten. Maybe Google assumes "West" from your location ... Did you try from my answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should compare geography with geography OR geometry with geometry.
And also you need to set the SRID.

So in your case you need

```
WHERE ST_DWithin(geom::geography, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(79.3832,43.6532),4326)::geography, 50000);
```

OR

```
WHERE ST_DWithin(geom::geography, ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;Point(79.3832 43.6532)'), 50000);
```

Then, from your profile details, I bet the longitude must be **-79.3832**, because currently you're searching for cities around a place in southeastern Kasachstan with not much around, while you probably want to search cities around Toronto.

```
WHERE ST_DWithin(geom::geography, ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;Point(-79.3832 43.6532)'), 50000);
```

Comment: Thanks! :) I really appreciate the help. That solved my problem.